# Search using dictionary with re.compile()

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, parsing

I ran into a problem while creating a parser. The line I want to parse in a txt file looks like this:

`'>NAME=  (various_names_here)'`

Every time I see this `">Name="` I want to read in the line.

My dictionary has an item:

```
my_dict = {
    'name': re.compile(r'>NAME=  (?P<name>.*)\n'),
}
```

Reading my txt file in by line with a `if` command for looking for `"name"`, I never find these lines.

While I'm getting close I can't find the correct syntax to read this line in. It seems I can't quite figure out how to handle the lack of white space between `>NAME=` and `(***)`.

Comment: Where is this `if` statement of yours? Also please put the example contents of your file in a text block so we can see what it looks like. I can't tell if `'` if part of your file or not.

Comment: What is the purpose of dictionary?

Comment: Wouldn't the `r` before the string cause you to search for a literal `"\n"` at the end of your match and not a new line which I think is what you're looking for?

Comment: @SyntaxVoid Actually that part is right. The `r` is to prevent the backslash plague.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add code showing how you are using the compiled regexes in the dictionary.

Comment: Your [**expression works**](https://regex101.com/r/PbeMSx/2/) - just add the caret (`^`) and use the multiline flag on the whole string (not line by line, that is).

Comment: The ' is not part of the expression. The editor here would delete the >. Don't know why. It seems like this should be easy. My code works if I go into the text file and add a space after the = sign. Without the space between the = sign and the (, the part of my code searching, match = my.search(line) will not match the 'name' name in my dictionary.

Comment: I tried the ^ to no avail. Perhaps I'm not getting the syntax correct?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to match something like this:

`>NAME=  (Bob)`

your regex pattern has to be modified like this:

`>NAME=  \((?P<name>.*)\)\n`

otherwise the round brackets won't be matched.

The pattern above will match:

`name = Bob`